# The "bitcoin" tag and bitcoin.stackexchange

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

So I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563124/blockchain-api-redirects-to-page), which is tagged with only [bitcoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin), and asked on Stack Overflow.

Seeing this question made me genuinely intrigued by the existence of the [bitcoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin) tag on Stack Overflow.

Since there is a [Bitcoin Stack Exchange](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) site, it seems logical to me that every bitcoin-related question should be asked there.

Is there any reason to allow to places for such questions?

Besides, is it okay to close questions (on Stack Overflow) that are tagged with only [bitcoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin) and not concretely related to programming?

Comment: there is also a tag named [tag:apple] on SO main, while we also have [cooking.se](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) ... in all seriousness, if a question is about programming with API's that involve bitcoins it is on-topic on Stack Overflow. Questions can be on-topic on separate sites.

Comment: @rene That's fair enough, but isn't it a bit contrary to stackexchange's philosophy to allow a question to be on-topic on several places? Though I agree that there'd always be ambiguous questions.

Comment: I don't recall a philosophy that mandates strict separation of topics. There is a philosophy that each community get to flesh out what is on-topic on their meta. Sometimes that leads to cross-overs, sometimes to new proposals on Area 51.

Comment: I retagged that question with [blockchain.info] tag, there are many more as I see, but they tend to be unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the question you mention is lacking an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it still covers

> a specific programming problem

so, if an MCVE is added, it's probably [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. It's probably on topic for Bitcoin Stack Exchange as well, given the history of [api](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) questions they have. <sub>I'm wondering what they mean by ['programming technique'](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) though, which they consider off-topic.</sub> Overlap between the scope of different sites is sometimes unavoidable, but this has not led to real problems yet. We sometimes see users posting the same question on different sites, but that's about it.

> Besides, is it okay to close questions (on stackoverflow) that are tagged with only "bitcoin" and not concretely related to programming?

Yes, that would be the correct action. I would also add a comment pointing to the existence of [Bitcoin Stack Exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You convinced me. BTW, thanks for the edit, I didn't know about the [tag:] formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I think the usage of bitcoin tag is ambiguous. Oh, yes, anything related with bitcoin, but bitcoin is complex enough, with many libraries, tools, and method that makes it as useful as (be warned, this tag can bring deep sadness and drain down and close votes) [programming-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages). They aren't asking about bitcoin proper, but the library/api/etc. that happens to be useful in manipulating bitcoin information. For me, this tag is homologous to tagging your question with the [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hash) tag when you are asking about [bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bcrypt) function/libraries, the later used for hashing, but more precise describing what your question is about, which would improve the chances of having a satisfactory answer.

tl;DR: this tag needs to be disambiguated.